# Is there a way to set the For property of label otherwise than ID of an element?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've this code for a view (ASP.NET MVC3), and I'm trying to add a for attribute on both the labels

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sanctioned, true, new { @checked = "checked"})                

 <label For="">Yes</label>

 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sanctioned, false, new { })

 <label For="">No</label>
```

I know it can be assigning an ID to both the radio buttons and refer them in For attribute of Labels respectively, but the situation here is, when I'm setting the IDs other than default, my Model is not getting posted back to controller. So, is there any way or work around to assign For attribute of Label control to point to the Radio buttons? Any suggestion or Feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This always works normal for me without "For" attribute and Label:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sanctioned, true, new { @checked = "checked"}) Yes
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sanctioned, false) No
```

May be I don't understand your question currectly, but why you really need it?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work that way. When you set the ID of an element in For attribute of a Label, the corresponding Label works as a pointer to that referenced element. 

In above case, If the For attribute of labels are set with respective IDs of RadioButtons, You can click on the text "Yes" , "No" to activate the corresponding radio button.